# how can I arrange a data based on alternative columns

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
df<-structure(list(A = c(0.7, 2.083, 2.517, 2.667, 3.883, 4.5), B = c(111L, 
131747L, 23428L, 12528L, 1055L, 881L), A.1 = c(1.4, 1.65, 2.1, 
2.267, 3.017, 3.383), B.1 = c(2370L, 179289L, 21690L, 10383L, 
816L, 637L), A.2 = c(0.85, 1.633, 2.117, 2.267, 3.567, 5.35), 
    B.2 = c(520L, 54607L, 13677L, 13448L, 1346L, 772L)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "A.1", "B.1", "A.2", "B.2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to make a unique column from column 1, 3 and so on 
Then assign the values to each of the numbers (if there is not any number, set 0)

I want to output to be like below

To make the question clear. First we look at column 1 to any other odd number column. Then we find the smaller value, it will become the first value (in this case 0.7) then we check in the even column to see based on their odd column if they have any value. so A was the first value and B had the value but we did not see the 0.7 in A.1 and not A.2 so it will be zero

```
A,A.1,A.2   B      B.1  B.2
    0.7    111     0    0
    0.85    0      0    520
    1.4     0   2370    0
    1.633   0      0    54607
    1.65    0   179289  0
    2.083   131747  0   0
    2.1    0    21690   0
    2.117   0   0   13677
    2.267   0   10383   13448
    2.517   23428   0   0
    2.667   12528   0   0
    3.017   0      816  0
    3.383   0      637  0
    3.567   0       0   1346
    3.883   1055    0   0
    4.5     881     0   0
    5.35    0   0   772
```

Comment: @akrun first we put the values from column 1, 3, 5 and any other odd column in one column. Then we assign the related values to it

Comment: @akrun I explained a little bit also above

Comment: @akrun no, if you look at the data, in this case we have 6 columns. so we merge the A, A.1 and A.2 into one column (unique and descending order) then we look at B, B.1 and B.2 to see if they had any value which corresponded to their previous column. A belong to B, A.1 belong to B.1 and A.2 belong to B.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `base R`

```
v1 <-  sort(unique(unlist(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], use.names = FALSE)))
res <- data.frame(A = v1, mapply(`[`,df[c(FALSE, TRUE)], lapply(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
         function(x) match(v1, x))))
res[is.na(res)] <- 0
res
#        A      B    B.1   B.2
#1  0.700    111      0     0
#2  0.850      0      0   520
#3  1.400      0   2370     0
#4  1.633      0      0 54607
#5  1.650      0 179289     0
#6  2.083 131747      0     0
#7  2.100      0  21690     0
#8  2.117      0      0 13677
#9  2.267      0  10383 13448
#10 2.517  23428      0     0
#11 2.667  12528      0     0
#12 3.017      0    816     0
#13 3.383      0    637     0
#14 3.567      0      0  1346
#15 3.883   1055      0     0
#16 4.500    881      0     0
#17 5.350      0      0   772
```